# Unable to 'catch' unhandled exception from 'Connect-AzAccount' - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Main issue: Unhandled exception, even though commands are inside try/catch.

I'm having an issue where our program that runs in a loop, and works 99% of the time is occasionally getting an error with Azure authentication.  Maybe once a week.  Basically anytime it cant reach Azure. The function is not critical so I want to catch it, log that it happened, and continue on with life.

The problem is, even though there is only one area of code that calls Azure, and its in a try-catch, its not catching. Instead it crashes like an ungraceful baby deer on an frozen lake with thin ice.  Has anyone run into this, or have ideas about this?

```
function Do-AzureStuff {
     param(
        # xref configs
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)]
        [ref]$ref,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)]
        [ref]$ref2

     )
    try{
        #Variables like AzureTenantId defined above, function is effectivly using script scope for those I believe.
        Connect-AzAccount -ApplicationId $azureAppId -Tenant $azureTenantId -CertificateThumbprint $azureCertificate -ErrorAction Stop

        $storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $azureStorageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount -ErrorAction Stop

        Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "my-container" -Blob $myImportantInfo1 -Context $storageContext -Destination $blobDestination -force -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "my-container" -Blob $myImportantInfo2 -Context $storageContext -Destination $blobDestination2 -force -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null

        $ref.Value = Get-Content "$blobDestination1" | ConvertFrom-Json;
        $ref2.Value = Get-Content "$blobDestination2" | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable;

        $err = $($ref2.Value.Secret = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $azureVault -Name $preDefined).SecretValue ) 2>&1

        #if err has a value...
        if ($null -ne $err) {
            $logInformation = "<p>Failed to get key from vault for ...</p>"
            #custom func
            LogThis "ProcessName" $logInformation $err
        }
            
    }catch{
        $err = "Unable to update xrefs, $_"
        #custom func
        LogThis "Mains script" "Faile to get Azure stuff" (get-error)
    }
}
```

I've tried explicitly adding stop action but I'm still getting the same windows event error below, and finding that our script has failed during the process after the fact. I have good Logging in place and know that the code breaks here, because of logging just before, and missing logging just after. Including no log from the catch potion of this code. There's also a windows event kernel error right after this one below, but it looks like its just the same error bubbling up to the kernel since its "unhandled" in my try-catch block.

The time also lines up exactly with this windows event error...

> Application: pwsh.exe CoreCLR Version: 7.0.923.32018 .NET Version: 7.0.9 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: ClientCertificateCredential authentication failed: Retry failed after 2 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (The operation was cancelled because it exceeded the configured timeout of 0:01:40. Network timeout can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout.) (The operation was canceled.) See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/clientcertificatecredential/troubleshoot ---> System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 2 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (The operation was cancelled because it exceeded the configured timeout of 0:01:40. Network timeout can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout.) (The operation was canceled.) ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was cancelled because it exceeded the configured timeout of 0:01:40. Network timeout can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ThrowIfCancellationRequestedOrTimeout(CancellationToken originalToken, CancellationToken timeoutToken, Exception inner, TimeSpan timeout) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.SendRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Core.HttpPipelineMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.ExecuteAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, HttpContent body, HttpMethod method, ICoreLogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.ExecuteWithRetryAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, HttpContent body, HttpMethod method, ICoreLogger logger, Boolean doNotThrow, Boolean retry, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.SendPostAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, HttpContent body, ICoreLogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Http.HttpManager.SendPostAsync(Uri endpoint, IDictionary`2 headers, IDictionary`2 bodyParameters, ICoreLogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.ExecuteRequestAsync[T](Uri endPoint, HttpMethod method, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean expectErrorsOn200OK, Boolean addCommonHeaders) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.GetTokenAsync(Uri endPoint, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean addCommonHeaders) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendHttpAndClearTelemetryAsync(String tokenEndpoint, ICoreLogger logger) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendTokenRequestAsync(IDictionary`2 additionalBodyParameters, String scopeOverride, String tokenEndpointOverride, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.FetchNewAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenForClientParameters clientParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Identity.AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilderExtensions.ExecuteAsync[T](AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder`1 builder, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClientCoreAsync(String[] scopes, String tenantId, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(String[] scopes, String tenantId, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Identity.ClientCertificateCredential.GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled. at Azure.Core.CancellationHelper.ThrowOperationCanceledException(Exception innerException, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Core.CancellationHelper.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ThrowIfCancellationRequestedOrTimeout(CancellationToken originalToken, CancellationToken timeoutToken, Exception inner, TimeSpan timeout) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)<--- --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage) at Azure.Identity.ClientCertificateCredential.GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Authenticators.MsalAccessToken.Renew() at Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Authenticators.MsalAccessToken.AuthorizeRequest(Action`2 authTokenSetter) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageContext.GetTokenStrFromAccessToken(IAccessToken accessToken) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageContext.<>c__DisplayClass99_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.TokenCredential.RenewTokenAsync(Object state) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_1(Object state) at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute() at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()

Comment: You are getting a null object and then continuing.  You should check for null objects and do not continue when null.  Intermittent errors like this are normally caused by timeouts.  It could be bit errors on the network or attempting to get credentials from a password server and server not responding quick enough.  Credentials failing usually occur a lot more often than what you are seeing.  It looks like you are looping when a failure occurs and retrying which is why you are seeing the error only 1% of the time.

Comment: I think what you're saying is accurate. I believe 'Connect-AzAccount' has a default of 3 tries before anything else. But the part I'm getting stuck at is, when it eventually does time out, shouldn't that exception be handled by this try/catch?

Comment: The error is being caught in another method/library.  A exception can only be caught once unless where it is caught uses a Throw.

Comment: ahhh  okay, that would make since. Hmm okay so then my question would turn into how can I "try" to get AZ stuff, and have the program continue rather than crash when it times out?

Comment: You need to test for null object and return when null instead of continuing.  When exception occur nothing is returned so the object is null

Comment: Wait are you saying to test for null in the .NET stack? The module that has "connect-AzAccount" and other functions I am using is made by Microsoft, its not a custom thing.  

Hmm. I don't really "want" this to happen again, but I did add some logging between "connect-AzAccount" and "New-AzSttorageConect" so I can hopefully find the exact command that's failing like this.  Maybe that would be the first step in modifying the Microsoft module.   I'll give that some effort and see where I can get,